# Get value of resolve from a request inside another request

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a promise function that performs a request to an api. Based on the response of that request there are a couple scenarios:

```
Library.prototype.method = function () {

return new Promise ( ( resolve, reject )=> {

request( options, function ( error, response, body ) {

   if ( scenario 1 ) {
   
      //do something that changes value from options and need to perform a new request

      request( options, function ( error, response, body ) {

         if ( response ) { resolve( true ) }

      })
   
   } 

   if ( scenario 2 ) {
   
      resolve( true )

   }


    }) 

  })

}
```

The case here is in the function call to the promise that contains those request I don't get the value of the nested request resolve.

```
library.method().then( ( response )=> {
  
  // scenario 2
  console.log( response ) // true
  // scenario 1
  console.log( response ) // never triggered

} )
```

If the function promise end in scenario 2 -> the promise returns true

If the function promise end in scenario 1 -> I don't receive anything as response

How can I get the resolve value from the inner request?

Comment: did you debug that your code execution is coming inside your secnario 1 inner if block where you are resolving the value to `true` ?

Comment: Yes, I have a console log in there but the resolve value isn't getting back.

Comment: So it is printing your `console` in that `if` block?

Comment: Yes, the console log is printed.

Comment: Could you provide a more complete code for this function? And where is the Promise defined?

Comment: @AlexanderPaschenko There's more code now

Comment: Have you checked if the second request is successful at all? Maybe there's an error and `if ( response ) { resolve( true ) }` will not be executed.

Comment: Since the `request()` library is now [deprecated](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) and not recommended for any new projects (discussion of that [here](https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142)), I would suggest you pick one of the alternatives that are already built around promises such as `got()`, `node-fetch()` or `axios()`, then none of your code will be needed as it's already built into a more modern http request library that already supports promises.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems good for me, but 1) you should check out the **response.statusCode**, and
2) you should **reject** when error...

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        request(url, function (error, response, body) {
          if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            resolve(....);
          } else {
            reject(......);
          }
        });
      });
```